# Getting variables from another .java file using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I've managed to get reflection working by getting and formatting the variables in the class that the toString() method is in.

```
public class ReadFile {

public int test1 =0;
public String test2 = "hello";
Boolean test3 = false;
int test4 = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    ReadFile test = new ReadFile();

    System.out.println(test);

}


public String toString(){

    //Make a string builder so we can build up a string
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    //Declare a new line constant
    final String NEW_LINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    //Gets the name of THIS Object
    result.append(this.getClass().getName() );
    result.append(" Class {" );
    result.append(NEW_LINE);

    //Determine fields declared in this class only (no fields of superclass)
    Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

    //Print field names paired with their values
    for ( Field field : fields  ) {
        result.append("  ");
        try {
            result.append(field.getType() + " "); 
            result.append( field.getName() );
            result.append(": ");
            //requires access to private field:
            result.append( field.get(this) );
        } catch ( IllegalAccessException ex ) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        result.append(NEW_LINE);
    }
    result.append("}");

    return result.toString();
}
}
```

However I was wondering whether it would be possible to specify a specific file in the directory for the `toString()` to work on?

I have tried getting a file and plugging it in the `System.out.println()` but the way I see it is you need to make an instance of a class and give it the instance for it to work. So I'm not sure how that can be done programatically.

I have been trying something like this:

```
    Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("D:\\Directory\\Foo\\Bar\\Test.java", args);

    File file = path.toFile();

    System.out.println(file);
```

However I don't get very far with it, I've mainly been seeing if I can convert the file into anything usable but I'm not sure what I need to be doing!

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to look into the ClassLoader API - you need to get an new [URLClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) and ask it to load your .java file into the JVM. You can then reflect on it.

Comment: Looking into the ClassLoader API helped a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to read the package information from the file (D:\Directory\Foo\Bar\Test.java) and than try to load it the class by its name:

```
Class.forName(nameOfTheClass)
```

[Java API Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by read the package information from (D:\Directory\Foo\Bar\Test.java)? I'm not really sure what you mean by that

Comment: The *Test.java* contains a `package ` line which declares to which package the `Test.java` belongs (you can also try to determine this from the directory structure instead). To use `Class.forName(..)` you need the package name and the class name.