# Parsing file .java for recognize String methods

Tags: java, parsing, reflection

I wonder if it is possible with some framework ( or some native library of java ) read a .java file as a string and return , always as a string , methods , properties , and so on. etc .

### Example

```
public class TestStackOverflow {

    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String manipulateValue(String b){
        String c = (this.value + b);
        this.value=c;
        return c;
    }
}
---------------------
```

I would like a method that will read the file TestStackOverflow.java I returned methods in String..

### example

```
File stoF= new File("/StackOverflow.java");
...
FrameworkParseJavaFile fpjf = new FrameworkParseJavaFile(stoF);
System.out.println("Methods print: " + fpjf.getMethods().get(0));
```

### ... results

```
Methods print:  public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
```

Thank you very much for every answer.
Ale

Comment: Use reflection. An API is already there for this purpose.

Comment: OP wants to read ".java" file (source code).  reflection will not help.

Comment: **step 1** convert .java to .class => [ClassLoader API](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14904478/1897935) , **step 2** use [Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

Comment: Or step 1: compile the code; step 2: run `javap`.